Upload File Cant Cancel Android Kotlin
im using this class to upload file
object UploadFileUtils {
    fun upload(uploadFileModel: UploadFileModel): String? {
        val connection: HttpURLConnection
        var outputStream: DataOutputStream? = null
        var inputStream: InputStream? = null
        val twoHyphens = "--"
        val boundary = "-----------------------------" + System.currentTimeMillis().toString()
        val lineEnd = "\r\n"
        var result: String? = ""
        var bytesRead: Int
        var bytesAvailable: Int
        var bufferSize: Int
        var bytesRead2: Int
        var bytesAvailable2: Int
        var bufferSize2: Int
        val buffer: ByteArray
        val buffer2: ByteArray
        val maxBufferSize = 4 * 1024 * 1024
        val str: Array<String>? = uploadFileModel.filepath?.split("/".toRegex())?.dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }?.toTypedArray()
        val fileName = str?.get(str.size - 1)
        try {
            val file = uploadFileModel.filepath?.let { File(it) }
            val fileInputStream = FileInputStream(file)
            val trustAllCerts = arrayOf<TrustManager>(
                @SuppressLint("CustomX509TrustManager")
                object : X509TrustManager {
                    @SuppressLint("TrustAllX509TrustManager")
                    @Throws(CertificateException::class)
                    override fun checkClientTrusted(chain: Array<X509Certificate?>?, authType: String?) {
                    }

                    @SuppressLint("TrustAllX509TrustManager")
                    @Throws(CertificateException::class)
                    override fun checkServerTrusted(chain: Array<X509Certificate?>?, authType: String?) {
                    }

                    override fun getAcceptedIssuers(): Array<X509Certificate>? {
                        return arrayOf()
                    }
                }
            )
            // Install the all-trusting trust manager
            val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")
            sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, SecureRandom())
            // Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
            val delegate = sslContext.socketFactory
            sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, SecureRandom())
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(delegate)
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(OkHostnameVerifier)
            val url = URL(uploadFileModel.urlTo)
            connection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
            connection.doInput = true
            connection.doOutput = true
            connection.useCaches = false
            connection.connectTimeout = 120000
            connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", uploadFileModel.cookie)
            connection.setRequestProperty("Referer", uploadFileModel.urlTo)
            connection.requestMethod = "POST"
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive")
            connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", uploadFileModel.userAgent)
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=$boundary")
            outputStream = DataOutputStream(connection.outputStream)
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd)
            outputStream.writeBytes(
                "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + uploadFileModel.filefield + "\"; filename=\"" + java.lang.String(
                    fileName?.toByteArray(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), Charsets.ISO_8859_1
                ) + "\"" + lineEnd
            )
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: ${uploadFileModel.fileMimeType}$lineEnd")
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd)
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available()
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize)
            buffer = ByteArray(bufferSize)
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)
            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize)
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available()
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize)
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)
            }
            if (uploadFileModel.isProfile) {
                val dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absoluteFile.toString() + "/Teamyar/Teamyar Images"
                val file2 = File(dir, "resize.jpg")
                val fileInputStream2 = FileInputStream(file2)
                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd)
                outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"new_file_2\"; filename=\"resize.jpg\"$lineEnd")
                outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: ${uploadFileModel.fileMimeType}$lineEnd")
                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd)
                bytesAvailable2 = fileInputStream2.available()
                bufferSize2 = Math.min(bytesAvailable2, maxBufferSize)
                buffer2 = ByteArray(bufferSize2)
                bytesRead2 = fileInputStream2.read(buffer2, 0, bufferSize2)
                while (bytesRead2 > 0) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer2, 0, bufferSize2)
                    bytesAvailable2 = fileInputStream2.available()
                    bufferSize2 = Math.min(bytesAvailable2, maxBufferSize)
                    bytesRead2 = fileInputStream2.read(buffer2, 0, bufferSize2)
                }
            }
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd)

            // Upload POST Data
            val keys: Iterator<String> = uploadFileModel.params.keys.iterator()
            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                val key = keys.next()
                val value: String = uploadFileModel.params.get(key).toString()
                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd)
                outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"$key\"$lineEnd")
                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd)
                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd)
                outputStream.writeBytes(value)
                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd)
            }
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd)
            try {
                if (connection.responseCode != HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    Log.e("uploaaad_failed", connection.responseMessage + connection.responseCode)
                } else {
                    Log.e("uploaaad_success", connection.responseMessage + connection.responseCode)
                }
                if (connection.responseCode == 413) result = "large"
                inputStream = connection.inputStream
                result = convertStreamToString(inputStream)
            } catch (e: InterruptedIOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            inputStream!!.close()
            fileInputStream.close()
            outputStream.flush()
            outputStream.close()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            result = "FailedConnect"
        }
        return result
    }

    private fun convertStreamToString(`is`: InputStream): String {
        val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(`is`))
        val sb = StringBuilder()
        var line: String? = null
        try {
            while (reader.readLine().also { line = it } != null) {
                sb.append(line)
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } finally {
            try {
                `is`.close()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
        return sb.toString()
    }
}

and here
in repository
    fun uploadMessage(message: ChatDetailsResponse.Message, dialogId: String) = flow {
        emit(
            UploadFileUtils.upload(
                UploadFileModel(
                    isProfile = false,
                    urlTo = "https://${RequestUtils.BASE_URL}/chat/dialog/send",
                    cookie = sharePref.getString(SharePrefConstant.SID),
                    params = mutableMapOf<String, String>().also {
                        it["login_user"] = userPrefModel()?.id.toString()
                        it["dialog_id"] = dialogId
                        it["act_topic"] = ""
                        if (message.replyId != null && message.replyId != "") it["reply_id"] = message.replyId
                        if (message.isSelfie == true) it["camera_type"] = "1"
                    },
                    filefield = "attachments",
                    fileMimeType = message.type.toString(),
                    userAgent = RequestUtils.USER_AGENT,
                    filepath = message.path
                )
            )
        )
    }.asResponseState().asUploadState()

in viewmodel
   fun uploadFile(message: ChatDetailsResponse.Message) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            uploadRepository.uploadMessage(message, dialogId = idContent).catch {
                it.message
            }.collect {
                Timber.tag("ChatVm").e("sendFile: %s", it)
                when (it) {
                    is UploadState.Error -> {
                        Timber.tag("TAG").e("sendFile Error: %s", it.exception?.message)
                    }

                    is UploadState.Loading -> {
                        messageList.add(0, message)
                        messageListLiveEvent.postValue(messageList)
                    }

                    is UploadState.Success -> {
                        getChatDetailsList(idContent)
                    }
                }
            }
        }.also {
            if (message.dateCreate != null)
                uploadJobs[message.path] = it
        }
    }

now the problem is i want to cancel this uploading but i couldnt
i use this
    val uploadJobs = HashMap<String?, Job>()


to store multiple files and store each job to handle that with cancele
this is chat application and each item should be in seprated job
with this method i cancel the job
    fun cancelUploadingClicked(message: ChatDetailsResponse.Message) {
        uploadJobs[message.dateCreate]?.cancel()
        uploadJobs.remove(message.dateCreate)
        // Remove the message from the list
        messageList.remove(message)
        // Update the messageListLiveEvent
        messageListLiveEvent.postValue(messageList)
    }

i dont know how could i cancel this
any one can help me
im using retrofit but i think that not worked
or maybe i couldnt handle with retorfit
help!
Canceling Uploading file in android Kotlin
